# alter md-tab to assign specific specific function 1 one of the tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have 3 tabs,

[ overview ][  about  ][   profile  ]

overview and about should perform as they are now but when I click on the profile tab, I would like a different function "rolloutItem()" to be called without affecting the tab content area

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but here we go.
You can use the selectChange event on the md-tab-group to trigger an event whenever a tab is selected:

```
<md-tab-group (selectChange)="onTabSelectChange($event)">
  <md-tab label="Overview"></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="About"></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Profile"></md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

And in your component:

```
onTabSelectChange(tabChange: MdTabChangeEvent) {
 // here you can check if the tab you want was selected and call your function, ex:
 if (tabChange.tab.textLabel === "Profile") {
     this.rolloutItem();
 }
}
```

You can review the docs for Material Tabs for more details on MdTabChangeEvent